# Binding to viewmodel not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one usercontrol called `ChannelControls` which is instanced 6 times inside an other one called CMiX. I want to bind one of `ChannelControls` property to a singleton class called cmixdata.

The datacontext is set in XAML :

```
<UserControl
        x:Class="CMiX.CMiX_UI"
        DataContext="{x:Static CMiX:CMiXData.Instance}"
```

And `ChannelControls` is used as follow :

```
<CMiX:ChannelControls x:Name="Layer0" ChannelSpriteCount="{Binding ChData[0].SpriteCount,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

`ChannelControls` property called `ChannelSpriteCount` is binding to `cmixdata` class, which is defined as so :

```
[Serializable]
public class CMiXData : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static CMiXData _instance = null;
    public static CMiXData Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new CMiXData();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    private CMiXData() { } //prevent instantiation from outside the class


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ChannelData> _ChData = new ObservableCollection<ChannelData>(new ChannelData[] { new ChannelData { SpriteCount = "1" }, new ChannelData { SpriteCount = "1" }, new ChannelData { SpriteCount = "1" }, new ChannelData { SpriteCount = "1" }, new ChannelData { SpriteCount = "1" }, new ChannelData { SpriteCount = "1" } });
    public ObservableCollection<ChannelData> ChData
    {
        get { return _ChData; }
        set
        {
            if (_ChData != value)
            {
                _ChData = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ChData");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the ChannelData class that hold data for each `ChannelControls` instanced in my application :

```
public class ChannelData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ChannelData() { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string _SpriteCount;
    public string SpriteCount
    {
        get { return _SpriteCount; }
        set
        {
            if (_SpriteCount != value)
            {
                _SpriteCount = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SpriteCount");
            }
        }
    }
```

Despite the fact that all class implement INotifyPropertyChange,  when `ChannelSpriteCount` changed, the binding doesn't update in cmixdata, it is still it's default value set in the constructor...

Comment: Please don't forget to mention that the current DataContext is already set to `CMiXData.Instance`.

Comment: Did you also set `Mode=TwoWay` on the Binding in the ChannelControl's XAML?

Comment: Try declaring the dependency property as SpriteCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChannelSpriteCount", typeof(string), typeof(ChannelControls), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnSpriteCallChanged)); and see if it eneters in OnSpriteCallChanged

Answer (score 1):

Try binding this way.

```
"{Binding Source={x:Static CMiXData.Instance}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=ChData[0].SpriteCount}"
```

UPD: As @lecloneur suggested `Mode=TwoWay` is necessary for it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. The singleton class is not updating to the new value.

Comment: ChData[0].SpriteCount does not fire its property changed.